# Get Top Referrals for a Page using the Google Analytics API in PHP?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the online Google Analytics API tool here to test results returned from different metrics.

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

My goal is to return the Top referrers on a per page basis on my blog site.  Generally to get stats related to just a speciofic page I simply use this in the `Filters` section...
 `ga:pagePath==/articles/13-best-code-schools-to-learn-programming-and-web-development/`

This will then return whatever results I am fetching but just for the page with the slug...
 `/articles/13-best-code-schools-to-learn-programming-and-web-development/`

Now this generally works however now that I am trying to get the top referrals for this page, it instead returns the top referrals for ALL pages instead!

Can someone help?

Below is an image showing the form filled in and then also list is each section with text...

**Dimensions:** `ga:source,ga:pagePath,ga:referralPath`
**Metrics:** `ga:pageviews,ga:sessionDuration,ga:exits`
**Filters:** `ga:pagePath==/articles/13-best-code-schools-to-learn-programming-and-web-development/, ga:medium==referral`

**start:** `2012-12-01`
**end:** `2014-12-30`

**This image below shows my result is instead the top referrals across ALL my pages instead of just the page in my FILTER**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Separate the two filters with a semicolon (AND), not a comma (OR).  Refer to the filter syntax section on [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference)

Your query is saying "return metrics where pagepath=...... OR medium=....."

You want:
"return metrics where pagepath=...... AND medium=....."